# Move page down to allow header graphic

Tags: html, css, header, internet-explorer-7, position

I am working with a program that allows me to add content, within a cell, in a table. All types of content is allowed, however, so I have added a reference to a stylesheet that is allowing me to re-brad the application.

The application is accessed via web browser inside our organization using mostly IE8 and IE10, as well as the application interface which use IE7 mode. Therefore, it has to be compatible with all of those browser modes at various screen resolutions.

What I am trying to accomplish is adding a header graphic, to a page that never had one. The layout is as such

```
<table width="60%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Here is my content
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Rest of page content here
```

I want a header image to cover the top part of the browser, so I have inserted an image

In the HTML I get to input

```
<img src="/pathtoimage.png" class="newhead">
```

CSS

```
.newhead
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Since the graphic is removed from the document flow, the rest of the page content wants to start behind the graphic.

Since the graphic will change heights, depending on browser size (adjusting proportionately on width), the content needs to move down by that same amount.

Any advice is appreciated on how to best accomplish this. I have been racking my brain at how to do this, and have it work with IE7 mode (I know, I know)

What I have been attempting is to use a transparent image that is 60% width of the header graphic (same height) - that way it would resize proportionately along with the header graphic) but getting it to properly fill the table, or stay 60%, or do anything according to plan has proven to not work.

Again, thank you for any help

Comment: May i ask why you make the image absolute? I,d make it `display:block; position:relative; max-width100%;` Like that it will scale correctly and following content will be shown under the image

Comment: My code is inside of a table that is 60% width. I cannot change that

Comment: And with your given code the image is stretching to the Body edge? That is Strange. Otherwise, you use IE... Before we think too much ;) is there no Way to Change the dom via js?

Comment: Or can you at least add a new row?

Comment: I edit a .txt file on the web server that is included inside of that <td>

More complete - it is
    ...
    <td>
        <usercode>
            [whatever I put in the txt file]
        </usercode>
    </td>


With absolute positioning, the image stretches to the body edge, not the table edge.
With block positioning, it is to the table edge.

And of course, it behaves differently in IE8, IE10 and IE7 mode (how the program launches)

Comment: Quick and dirty: you could inject javascript with your content. Even more dirty: append <img/></td></tr><tr><td>... In your txt. Ill Test around for a css Solution. But i dont know if there is something better then putting the absolute Image in a div that has a min-height... Which will not work for every image then...

Comment: I've been driving myself crazy with this for like 2 days now.

As dirty as it is, the whole </td></tr>.... method seems to solve my problem

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. But have a Look at that: http://jsfiddle.net/9j5Ck/ i can not fully Test Since i'am on a tablet atm.

Answer (score 1):

Why make the position absolute?  You can change the side of the header and have it push down as to whatever size you'd like it to be.

```
.newhead
{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

and in case you want to get rid of the default padding:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I want the graphic to fill the browser window, side to side, at the very top, no matter the size of the browser.
This way the image does not fill the window, or is too wide for the window, depending.

Comment: wrap your image inside a a div that is 100% width so the image will expand to fill it.

Comment: But that div is still within the 60% width table

Comment: You have no control of the rest of the page? How were you planning on moving it down even if it was a fixed height for the image?